# how to get match like tinder where every user has its own entry in table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, tinder

I am working on tinder like app and i want to fetch all match.In my matches table every user has it's own entry.so for one match there are two user and there are total two entry in table.

i tried sql query like given below

`select user_id, friend_id from matches where is_match = 1 group by user_id,friend_id`

with query i am getting below result
`

```
|--------------------------| 
|user_id|friend_id|is_match|
|--------------------------|
|   23  |    24   |    1   |
|--------------------------|
|   24  |    23   |    1   |
|--------------------------|
|   24  |    25   |    1   |
|--------------------------|
|   25  |    24   |    1   |
|--------------------------|
|   25  |    26   |    1   |
|--------------------------|
|   26   |   25   |    1   |
---------------------------
```

`

I want result like this.

`

```
|--------------------------|
|user_id|friend_id|is_match|
|--------------------------|
|   23  |    24   |    1   |
|--------------------------|
|   24  |    25   |    1   |
|--------------------------|
|   25  |    26   |    1   |
|--------------------------|
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the results you want by sorting the `user_id` and `friend_id` values and then selecting only `DISTINCT` pairs. Note no `GROUP_BY` should be required.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(user_id, friend_id) AS user1, GREATEST(user_id, friend_id) AS user2
FROM matches
WHERE is_match = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have two rows for each pair, then a simple solution is:

```
SELECT user_id, friend_id
FROM matches
WHERE is_match = 1 AND
      user_id < friend_id;
```

The use of `SELECT DISTINCT` (or `GROUP BY`) makes the query much more expensive.